# How to deifine a JNDI resource

Tags: jboss

how to define a JNDI resource on jboss 5?

My web application require a String value retrieved from the application server, on Tomcat I simply define my resource as string with value "mystring" but how can i do the same on jboss in which file?

Answer (score -1):

By calling a command in the application server; for example in Glassfish you can do it by calling create-custom-resource: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24928/jndi.htm#giowe .